# Uncaught Error: Could not find control by type: button- tinymce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have upgraded my rails app from 3.2.2 to 5.1.4. I updated tinymce version to 4.7.9. But on every page i am getting this error on console and tinymce is not working there.
**Error on console:**

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Could not find control by type: button
> ```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

**instruction/_form**

```
<%= tinymce_assets %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :mt_inst %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :mt_inst, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
  </p>
  <%= tinymce %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked this is giving error to Rails 5 app as well so you must download this tinymce-jquery from

> https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js

Then manually put it under *app/assets/javascripts/* folder and require it with the filename in *application.js*